# VB.Net Server & Java Client (Socket) Send & Receive Text

Tags: java, vb.net, sockets, tcp, client

I am new to Java programming
I wrote a simple Server(VB.NET) / Client(Java) program. 
Text from Java is send successfully to VB.Net but Response from VB.Net is not received in Java

Am I missing something?

Here are my Codes

VB.NET (Server)

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets, System.Text
Public Class Form1

Dim server As New TcpListener(9999)
Dim client As New TcpClient
Dim stream As NetworkStream

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Text = "Waiting...."
    server.Start()
    client = server.AcceptTcpClient
    'Receive msg'
    stream = client.GetStream()
    Dim r_byt(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    stream.Read(r_byt, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)
    Dim str As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(r_byt)
    Label1.Text = str
    'Send msg'
    Dim s_byt() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("got it")
    stream.Write(s_byt, 0, s_byt.Length)
    stream.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Java(Client)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class frmClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    frmClient myCli = new frmClient();
    myCli.run();

}

public void run() throws Exception{
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.100", 9999);
    PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    stream.println("Hello Server...");

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String string = buffer.readLine();
    System.out.println(string);
}
}
```

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at frmClient.run(frmClient.java:18)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Java` client looks fine. You just need to ensure you are sending a newline to match the `BufferedReader.readLine` statement. Replace:

```
Dim s_byt() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("got it")
```

with

```
Dim s_byt() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("got it" + vbCr)
```

in your server.

---

*Aside:* I would have a look at *threading* the server here as it blocks the app while listening for connections. Here is an [example](http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_multithreaded_server_socket_programming.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Reimeus, it worked, i am so stupid, i should have figured it out

Comment: having a little problem again, can u help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107006/vb-net-server-android-client-socket-send-receive

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure what the problem is here but I recommend splitting the string into chars and then writing the length of the array to the output stream. A for loop in java can then read the chars individually from the DataInputStream and then assemble it to form a string

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
String chars = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dis.readInt(); i ++) {
    chars += dis.readChar();
}
System.out.println(chars);
```

Also the vbs stream is not writing lines it is simply writing the characters. Try appending a breakline character to the end "got it\n"

Comment: Thanks 4 ur Help
but i still get this error

        `Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
 at frmClient.run(frmClient.java:19)
 at frmClient.main(frmClient.java:8)`

Comment: That is maybe because you are not actually writing the int in vbs? (facepalm)