# VB.Net Server & Android Client (Socket) Send & Receive

Tags: java, android, vb.net, sockets, tcp

I am new to Android programming I wrote a simple Server(VB.NET) / Client(Java/Android) program. Text from Android/Java is send successfully to VB.Net but Response from VB.Net is not received in Android/Java (**buffer.readLine()** *returns* **null**)

Am I missing something?

Here are my Codes

VB.NET (Server)

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

Dim server As New TcpListener(9999)
Dim client As New TcpClient
Dim stream As NetworkStream

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
    Me.Text = "Waiting...."
    Dim str As String
    server.Start()
    client = server.AcceptTcpClient
    stream = client.GetStream()
    Dim r_byt(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    stream.Read(r_byt, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)
    Str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(r_byt)
    Label1.Text = str
End Sub

Private Sub Responce_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Responce.Click
    Dim s_byt() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Got it" & vbCr)
    stream.Write(s_byt, 0, s_byt.Length)
    stream.Flush()
    stream.Close()
    client.Close()
    server.Stop()
End Sub
```

Android/Java(Client)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {

Button buttonSend, buttonReceive;
private static Socket socket = null;
PrintStream stream = null;
BufferedReader buffer = null;
String string = "a";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                socket = new Socket("192.168.0.104", 9999);
                stream = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                stream.println("Hi Server...");

                buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                string = buffer.readLine(); 
                Log.d("ServerActivity", " - " + string);
                buffer.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like you're on the right track... and I've use this same setup successfully in the past, so I know it's possible. Have you tried not closing the stream/client/server after you write on the C# side just to see what happens? Perhaps the connection is closed before Android reads it?

Comment: @thomas88wp thanks, but i tried, its not working

Comment: @thomas88wp thanks 4 ur tip, solved it using `Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` the connection was closing before Android could read it

Comment: i have the same problem. putting the thread to sleep did not work for me. Any other things that would cause this behaviour? @ThunderRoid

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a couple of issues:

- In the server side, you are trying to read something from the socket
  into `r_byt`, and you are not writing anything to it on cliente side.
  When you press the send button on server side, `r_byt` still null and
  that's what you receive on cliente side.
- On client side the call to socket read is blocking and after a few
  seconds will result in a ANR error (Application not Responding) in
  the cliente. You should move the socket read to a different thread
  from the UI. The newer Android versions don't even let you read from
  a socket in the UI thread.

Regards.

Comment: first, r_byt works fine
and i am writing to it - `stream.println("Hi Server...");`

second, w_byt is not working
and i am also writing to it - 
    `Dim s_byt() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Got it" & vbCr)
    stream.Write(s_byt, 0, s_byt.Length)`
   can u help